# How to write a loop over a given list in ATS?

Tags: ats

Suppose I have a list xs. How do I write the following style of loop in ATS:

```
foreach x in xs do process(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the old DIY-style (also: the classical ATS style), that is to say, using a tail-recursive function. Here's an example:

```
extern
fun
process (x: int): void
fun
loop {n:int} (xs: list(int, n)): void =
  case+ xs of
  | list_nil () => ()
  | list_cons (x, xs1) => let
    val () = process (x)
  in
    loop (xs1)
  end
// end of [loop]
```

You can run the full code [online](https://glot.io/snippets/ejoks5dbgh)

I think that this approach is preferable if none of the combinators or template functions provided in the libraries such as ATSLIB is suitable for your case.

Answer (score 0):

A combinator-based solution (for a `list0`-value):

```
(xs).foreach()(lam x => process(x))
```

In ATS, `foreach` is overloaded with many functions that do some form of sequence traversal.

There is also `iforeach` if the position of each element is needed:

```
(xs).iforeach()(lam (i, x) => process(i, x))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a **POOR** solution one needs to avoid!

A beginner of functional programming often does list traversal using the `list_get_at` function (which overloads the symbol `[]`). For instance, it is fairly common to see code that does more or less what the following line does:

```
(length(xs)).foreach()(lam i => process(xs[i])) // O(n^2)-time
```

This is EXTREMELY inefficient. Calling `list_get_at` inside a loop is almost always a bad idea!